# Where can I find the Templar Dens in Constantinople?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

Where are the Templar Dens?

Ideally I'd like to have a map of all of them in Constantinople.

Answer (score 5):

All of the maps I can find of all of Constantinople seem to be focused on finding the [Animus fragments](http://www.nowgamer.com/cheats/assassins-creed-revelations-cheats/1136364/assassins_creed_revelations_animus_fragment_map_guide.html), and not the Templar Dens, unfortunately.

The templar dens are pretty easy to locate, however.  Each one is marked on your map from the start of the game, I believe.  The icon looks a little odd, like a castle with three spires.  (I almost think they look like tiny top-down spaceships, like in Galaga or similar)  They often overlap with the "eagle" viewpoint icon.

[image]

If you go into the map's filter options, you can see what each icon represents, and you can toggle off all of them except for the Templar Dens, which should make finding them on the map super easy.  When you're in the area of a Templar Den, you'll know for a number of reasons:

- Shop icons are replaced by padlock icons, indicating that you can't buy the shop until you remove the den
- You'll see "castle tower" icons (similar to the rook in chess) which indicate sniper hideouts
- The map area around the den is in red, indicating it is a restricted area.

Here's a screenshot provided by [Jeff Mercado](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/8995/jeff-mercado) and poorly edited by me.  We've cleared the dens, so they show up with a different icon (an Assassin logo) - if you haven't cleared the dens yet, they'll show up like the icon above:

[image]

Comment: Alternatively you could just press [RB] in the map (or [R1]? on PS3 and [F3] on PC).  It will show the Templar/Assassin Influence in the city and highlight the regions in the map and the dens.

Comment: R1 on PS3, correct.